# How to nest one-to-many queries in one-to-one nested queries in Mybatis

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

This is my SQL and `resultmap`:

```
 <resultMap id="playerMap" type="player">
    <id column="playerId" property="id"/>
    <result column="playerName" property="name"/>
    <association property="team" javaType="Team">
        <id column="teamId" property="id"/>
        <result column="teamName" property="name"/>
    </association>
</resultMap>
<select id="selectPlayerById" resultMap="playerMap">
    select p.id playerId,p.name playerName,
    t.name teamName,t.id teamId
    from t_player p,t_team t
    where p.tid=t.id and p.id=#{id}
</select>
```

This is my result:

[image]

But the column of 'players' is null. How can I change my SQL statement so that this column can query the information of multiple players?

Answer (score 0):

first at all, you have to figure out, what kind of relationship(s) you want to represent.

for me it looks like you have class player with a member players. so, can a player have players?

if you want so select all or several players, you have to add a second `select`-element or to change the existing ones to something like that:

```
<select id="selectPlayers" resultMap="playerMap">
    select p.id playerId,p.name playerName,
    t.name teamName,t.id teamId
    from t_player p,t_team t
    where p.tid=t.id
</select>
```

you can extend the where clause as you need.

if you use `interfaces` to access methods in mybatis-xml-mappers, you have to add the following method to the specific `interface`:

```
List<Player> selectPlayers();
```

we can also combine both selects to something like that:

only one `select`-element in mapper-xml

```
<select id="selectPlayers" resultMap="playerMap">
    select p.id playerId,p.name playerName,
    t.name teamName,t.id teamId
    from t_player p,t_team t
    where p.tid=t.id
    <choose>
        <when test="id != null" >
            and p.id=#{id}
        </when>
        <when test="name != null" >
            and p.name=#{name}
        </when>
        <otherwise>

        </otherwise>
    </choose>
</select>
```

with one corresponding `interface`-method:

```
List<Player> selectPlayers(@Param("id") long id, @Param("name") String name);
```